# requestCode for onActivityResult Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am having this snippet of code in my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
      case 1:
        mImagePicker.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        break;

      case 10:
        mBraintreePackage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically both of this packages(I am using react-native) are using the same 
`requestCode` within the package.

```
// ImagePicker
static final int REQUEST_LAUNCH_CAMERA = 1;

// Braintree Android
private static final int PAYMENT_REQUEST = 1;
```

So I have to edit either one for this switch statement to work. Otherwise both statements will get executed.
Is it a suggested way or are there any way to do it without editing the package itself?

Comment: You have to change the value of wither one request code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a value inside your data Intent. Then check what kind of data you have there. Something like that:

```
if (data.getIntExtra(WHAT_REQUEST, -1) == 1){
            //do camera stuff
} else {
            //do payment
}
```

However, this is a bad approach. You have to overwrite requestcode somehow, because it is a default indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You could boolean flag like isPayClicked when Pay Button is clicked and check this value at onActivityResult on case 1: to perform Payment related code or Camera related code.

**declare:**

```
private boolean isPayClicked;
```

**onClick Method/Case for Payment button:**

```
isPayClicked = true;
//start Payment Intent
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

switch(requestCode) {
  case 1:
    if(isPayClicked){
      isPayClicked = false;
    //Perform payment related code
    }else{
    mImagePicker.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    break;

  case 10:
    mBraintreePackage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    break;
}
}
```